# Windows Batch: Save new output files in new folder with name of source directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

currently i concatentate multiple text files in my sub directories like this:

```
for /D %%J in ("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Test Annual Reports\*") do (
    > "%%~J\merge.txt" (
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
            dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "%%~J\*.txt" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"merge.txt"
        ') do (
            type "%%~J\%%I"
        )
    )
)
```

Can you please explain to me how I can alter the code, that it saves the "merge.txt"-files into a new directory, named after their source directory?
For example:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Outputdirectory\Subdirectory 2_merged.txt
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=U:\Users\hp\Desktop\Test Annual Reports"
SET "destdir=U:\Users\hp\Desktop\Outputdirectory"
MD "%destdir%">NUL 2>nul

for /D %%J in ("%sourcedir%\*") do (
    > "%destdir%\%%~nxJ_merge.txt" (
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
            dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "%%~J\*.txt" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"merge.txt"
        ') do (
            type "%%~J\%%I"
        )
    )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The only real change is that the destination filename is built from the `~nx` "name and extension" of `%%J` where `%%J` is interpreted as a filename.

Note that logically, `merge.txt` should not exist with this new method...

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for the explanation and code!!! You helped me a lot, this code works like a charm!